# How can I create a Timer app using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

As the the compose UI tools seem a lot simpler I imagine there is a relatively easy way to do this, but I haven't been able to find a sample project online, or in any tutorials.

The idea is simple, a basic UI that says "start timer" with 00:00 shown above. When you press the start timer the time moves up until you press "stop timer" which will be what the button reads below whilst timing. Every time you do this the app should record the time into a database of some kind.

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: You can check out my sample project which was created as part of the [#AndroidDevChallenge Jetpack Compose](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/03/android-dev-challenge-2.html). It is a countdown-timer instead of a stopwatch like you want. But it should be close enough to get you started.
Project:https://github.com/Farbklex/ComposeChallengeWeek2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetpack Compose is just a UI toolkit in Android, other things are same.
You can create UI from Kotlin code.
For Timer App, Business Code and Room Database/SQLLite database code will remain same.

You need to create Text View in Button in jetpack compose and add functionality left things are remain same.

If you want look a complete project made on Jetpack compose you can see this app [Kuberam: Jetpack Compose Project](https://github.com/rohitjakhar/Kuberam)

I hope your all doubt about compose will solve.